# ShellScript command to parse a pipedelimted file and split as 2 files, based on the 9th column( i.e after 8th pipe)

Tags: shell

I have a file such as this.

`TTT|ABCDE|80150511000000|89|19||180.0|998361|188344889||188344889||INTER|` , 
`TTT|ABCDE|80150511000000|89|19||180.0|998361||36061414||36061414|INTER|`

Notice in the 9th column(i.e after 8th pipe), I have a value in the first record, but no value in the second.

I am looking for a shellscript command that  parses this file and creates 2 file. One with 9th column as blank, and one without.  Is it possible to do in a single command, or else can you help with a shell script command.

Answer (score 1):

It is a variable-length record file based on your examples. I am not an expert of Shell script, but the following  is the logic for your reference:

1. Get the position of the 8th pipe. Say 45.
2. Get the position of the 9th pipe. Say 46.

If the gap between 8th pipe and 9th pipe is 1, it means that the record with 9th column as blank - goes to one file. Otherwise, it is without - goes to another file.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $yourstring | cut -d "|" -f 9`

This will output the 9th column of your string.

so if you do something like

```
while read line; do
   if [ `echo $line | cut -d "|" -f 9` != " " ]; then
      echo $line > $line 
   else
      touch "Blank file"
   fi
done < yourfile.txt
```

I am not sure about what you want. This script will create a file named by the 9th column or create a "Blank file" if 9th column is empty.